# Full Calendar changes background color only business Hours

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, background-color, fullcalendar-4

Past couple few weeks I have been working on Full Calendar. Everything is going as well until that requirement comes. So the requirement is that we need to change the background color of business hours in the calendar.

As you see the image I want to change the only background color of business hours. I tried to find on the web but eventually unable to find the proper solution of this, even I read out the documentation of full calendar there is nothing about how to change the background color of the business hours.

[image]

Comment: Please create JSFiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that when you set the business hours, only the parts which are **not** part of the business hours had their colour changed? Therefore, the business hours themselves stayed with the default colour.

Also, the times which fall within the business hours are simply left empty - there is no way to identify those areas specifically within the HTML. Whereas the non-business hours are implemented using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) with a specific colour set.

However these events are partially transparent, so if you change the default background colour of the whole calendar it also alters the underlying colour of the background events. This makes it harder to change the colour of the business-hours area.

The closest solution I could get to what you've asked for is to change the colour of the whole calendar, but then make the non-business hours have no transparency, so you cannot see the altered colour below them. It's done like this using a couple of simple CSS rules:

```
.fc-body
{
  background-color: #ECE4C6
}

.fc-nonbusiness
{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWGKaOB

(In case you don't realise, I discovered the classes to use by inspecting the HTML generated by fullCalendar, using my browser's Developer Tools.)

Comment: Yep! It's working but only in month view mode. Changed the calendar mode in day gird or time week gird mode so it will convert the color of a vertical timeline as well.

Comment: Take a look at my demo (https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWGKaOB) - it works in all views, with the same code. There shouldn't be a problem. It's not clear to me why it isn't working for you. If you have a specific issue, you'll need to fork my CodePen and change it so that it shows me the problem happening. Maybe something else in your code is interfering.